# reject li dom element having specific attributes

Tags: ruby, nokogiri

I am trying to get scrape a page and get dom elements which is a collection on links with Ruby and Nokogiri. So I have a collection of li's which has a specific attributes in some li's. I need to reject those li;s which has specific attributes and get all the link tags of those li's.

Here is my DOM looks like.

```
 <ul>
   <li class="carousel-list-item">
      <a itemprop="url" data-cr="CharNav23" class="property-icon property-icon-14" href="/max-and-shred/">
         <div itemprop="name" class="property-tooltip">
            Max &amp; Shred
         </div>
      </a>
   </li>
   <li class="carousel-list-item">
      <a itemprop="url" data-cr="CharNav24" class="property-icon property-icon-19" href="/rabbids-invasion/">
         <div itemprop="name" class="property-tooltip">
            Rabbids Invasion
         </div>
      </a>
   </li>
   <li data-sponsor="Sponsor" class="carousel-list-item">
      <a itemprop="url" data-cr="CharNav21" class="property-icon property-icon-40" target="_blank" href="http://pubads.g.doubleclick.net/gampad/clk?id=47616903&amp;iu=8675">
         <div itemprop="name" class="property-tooltip">
            LEGO Friends
         </div>
      </a>
   </li>
   <li class="carousel-list-item">
      <a itemprop="url" data-cr="CharNav24" class="property-icon property-icon-19" href="/rubyds-investment/">
         <div itemprop="name" class="property-tooltip">
            Rabbids Invasion
         </div>
      </a>
   </li>
</ul>
```

I need to collect all a tags whose lis dont have data-sponsor="Sponsor" attributes. I tried like the below but it includes all lis.

```
page.search('ul.carousel-list > li > a').map{ |link| make_absolute(link['href']) }
```

Answer (score 1):

The css way to do that is:

```
page.search('li:not([data-sponsor]) a')
```

or

```
page.search('li:not([data-sponsor=Sponsor]) a')
```

Probably a better option than xpath.

Answer (score 0):

You should try:

```
# this will give you all ul elements which has no attribute named 'data-sponsor'.
page.search('//ul[@class="carousel-list"]/li[not(@data-sponsor)]/a').map{ |link| make_absolute(link['href']) }
```

Comment: ('ul.carousel-list li[not(@data-sponsor)] > a') wont work?? I need to exclude li's which is in ul.carousel-list

Comment: @rubyist _I need to collect all a tags whose lis don't have `data-sponsor="Sponsor"` attributes_ what did you exactly mean by this?

Comment: @rubyist I gave you _Xpath_ expression, not the _CSS_ one. And you mixed both of those.

Comment: Sorry.. What I actually wanted was page.search('//ul[@class="carousel-list"]/li[not(@data-sponsor)]/a').map{ |link| make_absolute(link['href']) } and it worked. THanks.

Comment: @rubyist I had typo. I fixed it now. Please accept it if it worked for you.